# github: How to read the log from the command line without cloning

Tags: git, github

How can I read the log of a repository on Github from the command line without cloning the project?

In other words, if the bare repo is somewhere on my filesystem, I can read the log with:

```
git -C /media/git-repos/project.git log
```

How do I do it if the repo is on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @MarkAdelsberger answer, here is a quick python script that returns the log of a git repository on github. It expects two arguments, *user-name* and *repo-name*.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# github_log.py
import urllib2, json, sys

json_str = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/commits"
        .format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])).read()
commits = json.loads(json_str)

for c in commits:
    print c['sha'][0:8],c['commit']['message'].split('\n')[0]
```

**Example**

```
./github_log.py microsoft vscode
```

returns:

```
a4ae8375 fix decorations service test
45a71083 :lipstick:
9613370d update title area faster when opening a new group
42e1d19a composite bar polish css classes
8f4e125a Fix compilation errors
3170a7f5 Do not overload getConfiguration for sending it to extension host. Use getConfigurationData
f704a6c7 composite part: move pin / unpin / mode to compositePart
5276a4fc deco - proper explorer update on config change
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't.  But depending on *exactly* what you want, maybe you can make something kind of work.

The git command-line offers very limited interaction with remotes.  You usually just `fetch`, `push`, and `pull`.  (There are a few "less common" remote interactions, but none that are like what you're asking.)  But almost everything is done locally, by design.

The `-C` scenario you talk about is taking advantage of a *very* special case. You aren't actually interacting with your bare repo as a remote; you're telling git to access it like a local repo.  In fact, you *could* just `cd /media/git-repos/project-git` and then run `git log` normally; because it really is locally accessible.

But you can't `cd` to a github repo; your access is either via git's remote protocols, or via the API's provided by github.  (Similar situation would apply for any remote hosting service.)  In github's case specifically, those are web API's.

So if you know a web API request that would provide the desired results, you could feed that request through `curl`.  That's about the best you can do.  You might be able to get what you want from the `commits` API call, documented here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/