# Check the last commit of a repository without cloning it

Tags: git

I want to be able to get information about a repository (branches, commit history) without cloning the repository itself.

Could I do something like creating a local git repo, set it to track/upstream the remote repo and then fetch only meta data about the repo rather than the code base itself?

My end goal is just to get the commit history of the repo.

Thanks

Comment: You can e.g. clone a `--bare` repository without the working copy.

Comment: One hacky way is to use GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket UI to browse the repo and see commits.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778097/2020827

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: getting info about a change without a local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994004/git-getting-info-about-a-change-without-a-local-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+remote+branches+without+cloning

Answer (score 1):

If this is for GitHub, GitLab or BitBucket, then there is a Web UI which shows all the necessary information without cloning the repo.  For example, the link : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/master shows all the commits made in the TensorFlow repository.

Similar features exist in GitLab, BitBucket etc.

Comment: its for on-prem bitbucket which doesn't yet have API enabled, so I'm looking for a temporary work-around

Comment: In that case, cloning with depth 1 seems like a sensible way.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know of any built in way to download "just the commit" and "not the files stored in the commit".

---

If you want to look at a single commit :

```
git clone --depth 1
```

If you want to download the commits belonging to a single branch :

```
git clone --single-branch --branch the/branch
```

Comment: The need is to get info without cloning repo.

Comment: So the answer is not applicable.  Can you please either edit it or remove it?  Thanks.